# Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application

Tags: c#

I have created a Desktop application in visual studio 2.0.

One user  installed Microsoft .NET Framework 4 but when the application installing he get this message :.NET Framework Initialization Erroe

Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application"
What is this problem ??

Comment: If you start it at system startup it might show this error. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135667/unable-to-find-a-version-of-the-runtime-only-on-startup/9307445#9307445

Answer (score 3):

The user needs to install also .NET Redistributables for 2.0.

Comment: I just faced the same issue on a machine with .net 3.5 and 4.0 installed and this solved it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

open your project
right click on the solution, select Properties.

under "Application" there's a field:
Target framework

set it to framework 4

Comment: You need VS2010 to do this for 4.0. With VS2005 you can pick 1.1 and 2.0. With VS2008 you add 3.5.