# Unable to find a version of the runtime only on startup?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, startup

I have a very simple console app (just a `Console.Write()`) to test some start up functionality.  I dropped it in Window 7's start up folder, but when it runs I get a "Unable to find a version of the run-time to run this application."  The odd part is that if I go into the start up folder and actually run the program, it works fine.

Thoughts on what is causing this?

Comment: Already took a look at [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/c88a7e64-219b-4303-bd52-bccc7dc4c7c5)?

Comment: Guess: sounds like your app is trying to run before one of its dependencies is loaded... what version of .NET is it?

Comment: It should have 3.5 and 2.0 sp2 installed.

Comment: I've looked at many of the above, but my case seems special considering it only occurs at start up.  I've tried adding an app.config but to no avail.

Comment: Please see the FAQ regarding signatures in posts.

Comment: Is it only at startup or does it happen if you log off and log back on?

Comment: The start up folder will run it when you log in, and after it fails to run (with the aforementioned error), if I go into the folder and run it myself, it works fine.

Comment: @M.Babcock old habits, seems rude to ask people to fix crap for you with out at least thanking them for their time. Though I'll keep it in mind next time.

Comment: @mazzzzz - I'm aware that it'll run every time you login, my question was it if happens *every time* you login or if it was only after a reboot of cold start.

Comment: Haha, sorry, it sounded like an odd question. Just logging off and back on still produces the error (note I said logging off, not switch users, I don't believe it'll trigger if you log on from switching users; just an fyi).

Comment: @mazzzzz - You aren't using Mono are you?

Comment: Nope, straight 3.5 with Visual Studio 08.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following ["Unable to find a version of runtime to run this application" for 32bit app on 64bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512861/unable-to-find-a-version-of-runtime-to-run-this-application-for-32bit-app-on-6) you should add a copy to SysWOW64 in you're windows map. Let's see if it works.